# Folder Permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, development-environment, file-permissions, yii

What is the difference between drwxr-xr-x and drwxr-xr-x@

My dev environment web server (native Mac, no stack) started having problems writing to files and when I look at the different copies of the folders (on Mac OS) I see the addition of the @ sign. In those folders my web server can no longer write.

**EDIT**
Also in response to Matt below

This happened on my Mac, I originally had my vhosts set up to `users/*/Sites` but changed them back to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. This created permission problems with Yii so I added vhosts for both locations so I can build in `users/*/Sites` and sim host in `/Library/WebServer/Documents.` Now I can not write to `users/*/Sites` and where the `@` now appear. I do not see symlinks indicated in finder though. Any ideas on what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X, @ after the permissions indicates that the file has extended attributes (and maybe also an access control list); it indicates a symlink if it's after the filename.  You can add the `-@` option to `ls` to show xattrs and `-e` to show ACLs.  `ls -le@` will show the lot.  I'd guess you had some sort of deny rule in the ACLs, but since you've apparently deleted the folder it's a bit late to find out...

Answer (score 1):

The `@` indicates a symlink.

> ```
> / is a directory
> @ is a symlink
> | is a named pipe (fifo)
> = is a socket.
> * for executable files
> > is for a "door" -- a file type currently not implemented for Linux, but supported on Sun/Solaris.
> ```

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ls-append-indicators-774105/

Comment: thanks for the help.  This happened on my Mac, I originally had my vhosts set up to users/*/Sites but changed them back to /Library/WebServer/Documents.  This created permission problems with Yii so I added vhosts for both locations so I can build in users/*/Sites and sim host in /Library/WebServer/Documents.  Now I can not write to users/*/Sites and where the @ now appear.  I do not see symlinks indicated in finder though.  Any ideas on what went wrong?

Comment: Added dev-env back as a tag.  Modified question to include its relevance.

Comment: Ok I just deleted that folder and threw the contents back into a new version of the folder.  That got rid of that link.